# Solving Schrodinger equation for the hydrogen atom

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, differential-equations, hydrogen

In University Physics with Modern Physics by Hugh Freedman in Chapter 41.3 they go about solving the Schrodinger equation for the hydrogen atom.

At one step they say to substitute the following function:

[image]

which is a function of spherical coordinates into the Schrodinger equation below:

[image]

Once you do this you are supposed to get the three separate differential equations below:

[image]

My question is, how did they do this substitution step? I tried it myself and got something quite different.

It is my understanding that the solution to these differential equations gives the wave functions for electrons in a hydrogen atom.

Comment: Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Comment: Note : a notice in bold was added to the "ask a question" page about the use of Mathjax so it is disappointing to see new posts continue to post images instead.

Comment: *Once you do this you are supposed to get the three separate differential equations below*. **No**, you need to convert your SE from Cartesian coordinates to spherical coordinates first

Comment: An excellent 'beginners' guide' to solving the hydrogen SE here: https://users.aber.ac.uk/ruw/teach/327/hatom.php#:~:text=The%20ingredients,just%20a%20single%20proton%2C%20though.

Answer (score 1):

This is a rather standard method of finding solutions to Partial Differential Equations called [Separation of Variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables#Partial_differential_equations). The Wikipedia link I've added explains the method quite clearly.

The fundamental idea is that once you have substituted your "trial" separable solution (i.e. the solution is *separable* into a product of functions of one variable only), the partial derivatives turn into total derivatives of their respective functions. (Notice that this method doesn't guarantee that *all* or even any of the solutions do indeed look like this, it *assumes* that such a solution exists.)

Once this is done, you can keep all the terms that depend only on one variable to (say) the left hand side of the equation, and all the terms that depend on the other variable on the right hand side of the equation. These two terms must *always* be equal, and the argument then is that they must both be equal to a constant individually. The choice (and interpretation) of the constant usually depends on the boundary conditions, though it's sometimes more complicated.

In this case, you have three variables, but it's just a case of applying the above method sequentially. It's a pretty standard exercise that everyone does in an undergraduate physics course, or at least they should!

Comment: Nice answer. But it could perhaps have been useful to explain where the 'magic' numbers $m_l$ and $l$ come from?

Comment: $\hbar^2 l(l+1)$ is just the Casimir invariant of the $SO_{i\hbar}(3)$ group, whose Casimir operator in the representation acting on wavefunctions is proportional to $\Delta_{\mathbb{S}^2}$, the angular part of the laplacian in spherical coordinates. $m_l$ is the eigenvalue of $\pi_{w-f.}[\hat{L}_z]=-\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$, where $\pi_{w-f.}$ is the representation acting on wavefunctions.